# Generalized Additive Model (GAM) for air pollutant in R

Tags: r, gam

I want to analyze a dataset with GAM model. But I'm facing trouble for selecting appropriate splines for my each non linear predictor variable . Please recommend me some ways .

I want some advice related to my questions .